# Outputing y element after every nth elements in the list

Tags: list, recursion, f#

How do you write a F# recursive functions that insert the specified y element after every n elements in the list xs and work even when applied to infinite lists.

For example:
one is

Input

```
let something n y xs = ... 
    ...
```

Input

```
something 2 'O' ['a'; 'b'; 'c'; 'd'; 'e'; 'f'];;
```

Output

```
['a'; 'b'; 'O'; 'c'; 'd'; 'O'; 'e'; 'f'; 'O']
```

Input

```
something 3 'O' ['a'; 'b'; 'c'; 'd'; 'e'; 'f'];;
```

Output

```
['a'; 'b'; 'c'; 'O'; 'd'; 'e'; 'f'; 'O']
```

and the other one is

Input

```
something 5 'A' [1..10]
```

Output

```
['1'; '2'; '3'; '4'; '5'; 'A'; '6'; '7'; '8'; '9'; '10'; 'A']
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58847230/computer-science-programming-language with the same problems with the question.

Comment: Not at my computer right now but this doesn't sound like it would be to hard with a couple existing methods for collections. Is there a reason you want write a recursive method?

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a shot, if you guys don't mind

```ml
let all = [ 'a'; 'b'; 'c'; 'd'; 'e' ]

let rec insertEvery n value indexed =
    let loop = insertEvery n value
    match indexed with
    | [] -> []
    | (indx, hd) :: tl ->
        match indx with
        | i when n <> 0 && ((i + 1) % n) = 0 -> hd :: value :: loop tl
        | _ -> hd :: loop tl

all
|> List.indexed
|> insertEvery 3 'x'
|> printf "%A\n"
```

```
$ fsi insertEvery.fsx 
['a'; 'b'; 'c'; 'x'; 'd'; 'e']
```

Just getting into the ocamlish side ...
... constructive critics welcome
:)